# HQL error with subquery for a related entity

Tags: hibernate, hql

I've been having problems trying to retrieve a related entity using an HQL subquery. I have three entities: a `Customer` entity, an `Account` entity and an additional entity which I called `Relation`. Initially I had a many to many relationship between `Customer` and `Account`, but later I had to add this new entity called `Relation` because I needed to add additional information to the relation between `Customer` and `Account`. Since `Customer` is no longer mapped to any of the rest of the classes here in the problem I am going to leave it out.

- Address (only the interesting parts)

> @Entity(name = "Address")
>   @Table(name = "Address")
>   public class Address extends {
>   .....
>        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "address", 
>        orphanRemoval = true)
>        private Set relations = new HashSet();
>       @Column()
>       private String number = null;
>   .....
>   }

- Relation (only the interesting parts)

> @Entity(name = "Relation")
>   @Table(name = "CustomerAccount")
>   @IdClass(Relation.RelationId.class)
>   public class Relation {
>   ....
>       @Id
>       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
>       private Account account = null;
>       @Id
>       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
>       private Customer customer = null;
>   ....
>   }

What I am trying to obtain is the following:

- Given a specific `Customer` (using its Id) and a specific `Account` number, obtain the `Account` and its `Relation` to the specified customer (if there is any).

This is the hql query I am trying to execute to accomplished this:

> select account, (select relation from account.relations inner join relation.customer customer where customer.id = :id) from Account account where account.number = :number

The resulting sql is the following:

> select account0_.Id as col_0_0_, 
>        (select
>          (relations1_.AccountId,
>          relations1_.CustomerId)
>       from
>        CustomerAccount relations1_
>  
>       inner join
>        Customer customer2_
>  
>         on relations1_.CustomerId=customer2_.UserId
>  
>       inner join
>        OlsUser customer2_1_
>  
>         on customer2_.UserId=customer2_1_.Id
>  
>       where
>        account0_.Id=relations1_.AccountId
>  
>         and customer2_.UserId=?) as col_1_0_,
>       account0_.Id as Id0_,
>       account0_.number as AccountN2_0_,
>       account0_.Active as Active0_,
>       account0_.Application as Applicat4_0_,
>       account0_.Description as Descript8_0_,
>       account0_.LastUpdated as LastUpda9_0_,
>      from
>       Account account0_
>  
>      where
>       account0_.number = ?

I believe there is something wrong with the subquery in hql, and at last the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "(2, 3)"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:410)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:468)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:811) 


... 61 more
```

Which I relate to the specific part of the subquery but not sure what its happening underneath. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally.. As said before, I was complicating it. The query was more simple than that

`select account, relation from Account account left join 
account.relations relation with relation.customer.id = :id 
where account.number = :number`

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Address is in fact Account, right?

To answer your question : your query is much more complex than needed. All you need is

```
select account, relation from Relation relation
inner join relation.account account
where account.number = :number
and relation.customer.id = :customerId
```

Comment: Not really. In that case, if a Customer does not have a specific Relation with an Account, that query won't return anything. There is an Account A to which I have no relation, if I query for the account number and my Customer entity what I would like is at least to obtain the Account object, even though there is no relation, so the Relation side of that query should be null. I don't know if it is possible I just don't want to issue another query if possible

Comment: then the following should be OK : select account, relation from Account account left join account.relations relation left join relation.customer customer where relation.id is null or customer.id = :customerId

Comment: Not really same as above. It works when there is a relation for that customer with that account, but when there is no relation at all it fails to return any results. Even if there is an account for a given number.